# Parse first element of JSON array (getting data from google sheets)

Tags: arrays, json, parsing

I am developing an app in Android using Google sheets as DB and my resulting JSON object is of the format:

```
{"range":"Sheet1!A1:B3","majorDimension":"ROWS","values":[["question 1","answer1"],["question 2","answer2"],["question 3","answer3"]]}
```

I extract the JSON array from it and get:

```
[["question 1","answer1"],["question 2","answer2"],["question 3","answer3"]]
```

Now I want to separate the questions and save them into separate arrays, also answers into another array. Basically I want to break/parse each element of the JSON array, however I am only able to get the whole element and not the first value of each element.

Since I don't have any search criteria here how can I get the first/second value of each element separately?

Comment: Why dont you extract the first element and save it into one array and other into the second ?

Comment: thats exactly what i want to do but unable to extract from JSONArray

Answer (score 1):

You can try this below:

```
json_data = [["question 1","answer1"],["question 2","answer2"],["question 3","answer3"]]
questions = [i[0] for i in json_data]
answers = [i[1] for i in json_data]
```

Comment: thanks.i iterated through the arraylist and used split() and its working.